# Access External application(top window) as NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, apache-flex, flex4

I am accessing an adobe flex keyboard application as:

```
NSWindow *myMainWindow = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But I want to apply `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` (can only be applied to `NSPanel`).

So is there any way to apply/ access the top Window as `NSPanel` Object.

(If possible accessing the flex keyboard app through its name as `NSPanel` ?)